# Find if a font flavour/style is in separate file or generated by Windows

Tags: c#, windows, fonts

In Windows, using C#, one can check if a specific font style is available, but this does not tell if it is generated by windows from a Regular style (e.g. bold or italic can be generated like that), or there is a separate font file. Like for arial font, we have separate files: arial.ttf, arialbd.ttf, ariali.ttf, ...

My problem is, that we use a 3-rd party pdf export library, which seems to work ok with styles only, when there are such additional files for these styles. If they are not available, there is only Regular style from this one file present. To fix this, I need/would prefer to know, if a style has a separate file or not.

Windows has two classes: FontFamily, in System.Drawing and System.Windows.Media, but neither of them seem to answer this question, only if style is available. Or am I missing this functionality? Is there a way to determine such file?

I was thinking to just search C:\Windows\fonts, but is this always the only location of system fonts in recent windows versions?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean "generated by windows from a Regular style"? That is not something windows can do. It can get that style if there's a font collection, which are packed as single files, but it can't just magically "invent" a bold or italic version of a font. That's not how fonts work? It sounds like this is a question about how to ensure your 3rd party PDF library uses the correct fonts, so you should probably say which one it is, and tag your post for that library.

Comment: Windows does that, on this forum there is more about it:

Comment: https://forum.high-logic.com/viewtopic.php?t=5350 answer by Bhikkhu Pesala » Fri Dec 19, 2014 9:41 pm: "Windows creates false font styles for bold, italic, or bold italic, if they don't exist for any given typeface. They are called faux fonts and cause problems when producing PDF files. They are converted to curves, bloating the PDF file enormously in some cases. 

Therefore, one should never use the false font styles generated by Windows. ..."

Comment: However, when exporting to pdf from Word, it attaches (embedding, as far as I know) font stream in a way, that it can be read in italics, bold or bold-italics properly. I have to make that similar functionality as Word, regardless if the 3-rd part library prevents this or it is a bug, since the intent was to do it the same way as Word does that. My question about checking available font files is about their presence, since I think it is preferable to use font styles from the original ttf files and not from these generated "faux fonts".

Comment: Knowing if these files exist would allow me to make faux fonts only if there is such need, not in every case. But Windows is not very cooperative, it seems. One of the FamilyFonts have URI property, but in the debugger I get null, when I know, the file is there in C:\Windows\Fonts.

Comment: hm, that forum post lacks a link to microsoft's knowledge base explaining that really is a thing, which would usually also be where you'd find the links to the documentation around working with them as a developer.